# How to revome a directory (folder) in c++ . I am using rmdir(); but it doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, file

Here is the part of my code.

```
cin>>batch_serial;

    makefilename=".//studentData//batch"+to_string(batch_serial);
        filename=&makefilename[0];
        cout<<filename;                 //bug
        if(rmdir(filename)==0)
        {
            cout<<"Batch removed Succecfully";
        }
        else
            cout<<"Couldn't remove Batch";
```

Comment: use proper c++ functions https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Comment: `rmdir(makefilename.c_str())`

Comment: Could you explain what the "bug" comment signifies?

Comment: What does "doesn't work properly mean"? Doesn't compile? Doesn't remove the directory? Something else? Note that you shouldn't use `//` as your directory separator only back slashes need to be doubled to bypass during escaping